# NullPointerException on onDestroy() method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I got this problem while exiting my app: when You click 'Back' button the LeadBolt ExitAd appears. Then You click 'No' and app exits and toast appears with "This app has stopped."

So, there's something with ad OR it's something with setting MediaPlayer to null.

Code looks like this:

```
alarm = new MediaPlayer();
...     
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (alarm != null) {
            alarm.release();
            alarm = null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (alarm != null) {
            alarm.release();
            alarm = null;
        }

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        myController.destroyAd();
//      myController2.destroyAd();
        if (adView != null) {
              adView.destroy();
            }
        super.onDestroy();
        if (alarm != null) {
            alarm.release();
            alarm = null;
        }
    }
```

Exception logs:

```
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.klangstudios.car_pilot_remote/com.my_company.my_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3451)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at com.klangstudios.car_pilot_remote.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:209)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5273)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1110)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3438)
11-05 11:06:49.130: E/AndroidRuntime(2019):     ... 11 more
```

Anyone got similar problem?

Comment: to me seems that myController is null, could it be?

Comment: Would you tell me which line is this: at com.klangstudios.car_pilot_remote.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:209) ?

Comment: are you sure super.ondestroy() is at the right place ?

Comment: Yup, that's the only thing that you try to access without prior check if it isn't `null` (you do this check for `alarm` and `adView`).

Comment: My guess: line 209 is myController.destroyAd(); and you're getting myController as null.

Comment: by the way, you forget to @override ondestroy()

Comment: When the stack trace tells you which line the problem is on, remember that we can't see the line numbers. For clarity please can you indicate which line the NPE is actually occurring on?

Comment: @yahya: You're right - it's myController.destroyAd();
ScottHelme: well, I don't really know how to read LogCat so I pasted the whole error here.

I suspect that it might be a problem with MediaPlayer.

Comment: @HpTerm true, just added Override, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you should replace the following:

```
    myController.destroyAd();
```

with this:

```
 if(myController!= null) {
      myController.destroyAd();
}
```

then try it. You will avoid getting a null pointer exception, because if myController is null, then the program won't be destroying something that doesn't exist

Comment: Wait, that worked! I don't get any fatal errors now, just in LogCat I found that: 
E/webview(10281): Error: WebView.destroy() called while still attached!
but it doesn't any harm. Thanks! I'm shocked since LeadBolt implementing guides din't included checking anything.

Comment: My crashlytics app send me that now there is a problem on line 210, so the same thing as been. The difference is that user isn't affected which is a good thing. Still, maybe we can do something about this so it will be free of errors :)